# Overloading methods in Java?

Tags: java, class, methods, overloading

I am still a bit new to Java and I could use some help with this code please, so far i wrote the methods and what each methods should do but I honestly have no idea how to do the overloading effect and make it work so I would appreciate a simple explanation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment3 {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myMethod();
}
public static void myMethod(){
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java 1 ");

}
public static void myMethod(String msg, int counter){
    System.out.println("Enter your custom messege please: ");
    msg = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter how many times do you wish to print the messsege: ");
    counter = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
public static void myMethod(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){

    System.out.println("Please enter a lowerlimit: ");
    lowerLimit = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter an upperlimit: ");
    upperLimit = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Press 1 for ascending order: ");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for descending order: ");
    System.out.println("Make your selection");
    int user1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How frequent do you wish the messege to be printed");
    int interval = input.nextInt();

    switch(user1){
    case 1:
        for(int counter = lowerLimit; counter <= upperLimit; counter += interval){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for(int counter = upperLimit; counter <= lowerLimit; counter -= interval){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        break;
        default :
            System.out.println("Something went wrong !!!");
    }

}
public static void myMethod(double number1, double number2){

    number1 = (Math.random() * 100);
    number2 = (Math.random() * 100);
    double product = (number1 * number2);

    System.out.println("The product of " + number1 + " and " + number2 + " is " + product);
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment:

You just need to call the two other "myMethod" in your main, with their respective signatures:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Call without argument
        myMethod();

        // Call with String and integer
        myMethod("test", 42);

        // Call with Integer and Integer
        myMethod(42, 666);
    }
```

The right ones will be called then. Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Thank you very much, that did help explaining and fixing the code, i guess i need more practice and digging to perfect this.

Thank you all again

Answer (score 1):

Your `myMethod` method is already overloaded. An overloaded method is just a method that can accept two or more different sets of parameters. (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

For example :

```
public void foo(int a) {
  System.out.println("Printing out the int " + a);
}

public void foo(double a) {
  System.out.println("Printing out the double " + a);
}
```

Foo has two possible parameter sets, one that accepts an `int` and one that accepts a `double`. Now, if you do this :

```
int a = 10;
double b = 10.5;

foo(a);
foo(b);
```

It'll return :

```
Printing out the int 10
Printing out the double 10.5
```

Comment: I'd add that this applies to both _static_ and _instance_ methods (the OP has static methods). Also provide a link from Oracle docs or Java Lang Spec.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response but i guess i did not explain my problem propperly.

This code is missing the part that is responsible for calling out the methods by their function, as in i do not know how to tell the compiler to call a method that is responsible for a specific function, all i was able to get from this code when trying to run it is the message that says : Welcome to java 1

Comment: Well that is because it is the only method being called in your main method: myMethod(); ! The other methods are never called

Answer (score 0):

Above post has your answer, Your myMethod method is already overloaded but Method Overloading is a feature that allows a class to have two or more methods having same name, if their argument lists are different.
You have your method which accepts different parameters with different datatypes